# Extending pylint to deal with template variables?

Tags: python, pylint

I wrote the [say](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/say) module to make formatted printing simpler and more straightforward. E.g.

```
say("{len(items)} retrieved; {n_errors} encountered")
```

rather than:

```
print("{0} retrieved; {1} encountered".format(len(items), n_errors))
```

That part is going great. But I like to run `pylint` to look for gotchas and mistakes. Unfortunately, many data values are constructed solely for their usefulness in output operations, and pylint cannot "see" that use in a `say` call (or any other templates output mechanism) constitutes a genuine use of the variable. Wave after wave of W0612 (unused-variable) warnings can result.

It's possible to simply put in ignore comments, but that seems retrograde. I'd rather just extend pylint to understand that variables used in `say()` templates are, in fact, used.

`.../pylint/checkers/variables.py` appears to be the place to add this check, but I'm unfamiliar with the codebase. Any hints or suggestions as to how to register variables used in format-style strings are, indeed, properly used?

Comment: Even just guessing about `pylint`'s operation, I'd say that it probably doesn't do much with the contents of strings, and is even less likely to care about format templates within those strings, so teaching it how to parse and analyze those is going to be a decent amount of work.

Comment: A better place to ask this question is the (Python) Code Quality mailing list. Information available at http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/code-quality

Answer (score 0):

In the 'variables' checker, used variable are removed from the `self._to_consume[-1]` list (`self` being the checker and `[-1]` because this is a stack of per function variables list.

Anyway, Alex is right that further discussion on this topic should rather go to the code-quality mailing list.

Comment: Thanks. I will repost there